# Basic programming sample of OpenCL from Apple fails to run on GPU

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, opencl

I started learning some basics about OpenCL a while ago and decided to give the ["Basic programming sample"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/ExampleHelloWorld/Example_HelloWorld.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008312-CH112-SW2) from Apple a go. I runs OK on CPU, but when I select GPU as the target device I get err = -45 from

`err = gclExecKernelAPPLE(k, ndrange, &kargs);`

This error code translates to `CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE`. Any idea how can I correct the sample code?

Automatically generated `kernel.cl.c` code looks like this (+ includes on top):

```
static void initBlocks(void);

// Initialize static data structures
static block_kernel_pair pair_map[1] = {
    { NULL, NULL }
};

static block_kernel_map bmap = { 0, 1, initBlocks, pair_map };

// Block function
void (^square_kernel)(const cl_ndrange *ndrange, cl_float* input, cl_float* output) =
^(const cl_ndrange *ndrange, cl_float* input, cl_float* output) {
    int err = 0;
    cl_kernel k = bmap.map[0].kernel;
    if (!k) {
        initBlocks();
        k = bmap.map[0].kernel;
    }
    if (!k)
        gcl_log_fatal("kernel square does not exist for device");
    kargs_struct kargs;
    gclCreateArgsAPPLE(k, &kargs);
    err |= gclSetKernelArgMemAPPLE(k, 0, input, &kargs);
    err |= gclSetKernelArgMemAPPLE(k, 1, output, &kargs);
    gcl_log_cl_fatal(err, "setting argument for square failed");

    err = gclExecKernelAPPLE(k, ndrange, &kargs);

    gcl_log_cl_fatal(err, "Executing square failed");
    gclDeleteArgsAPPLE(k, &kargs);
};

// Initialization functions
static void initBlocks(void) {
    const char* build_opts = " -cl-std=CL1.1";
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once,
    ^{ int err = gclBuildProgramBinaryAPPLE("OpenCL/kernel.cl", "", &bmap, build_opts);
        if (!err) {
            assert(bmap.map[0].block_ptr == square_kernel && "mismatch block");
            bmap.map[0].kernel = clCreateKernel(bmap.program, "square", &err);
        }
    });
}

__attribute__((constructor))
static void RegisterMap(void) {
    gclRegisterBlockKernelMap(&bmap);
    bmap.map[0].block_ptr = square_kernel;
}
```

Comment: I am assuming you are creating the Queue using GPU, but does this GPU support openCL?

Comment: Yes, created queue using gpu, and yes, gpu supports opencl (ati HD6750M). In fact it runs normally when using non-apple approach. I just want to know why the "official" way fails?

Comment: what is the behavior if you don't pass the build options, i.e build_opts = "-cl-std=CL1.1"... ? do you still get this error ?

Comment: @ocluser I cant skip this particular option, xcode includes it automatically. However there is one option I can change. It's architectures. By default it is a string "i386 x86_64 gpu_32". Whatever change I make here, it runs ok on CPU but fails with -45 on GPU. Even when I put only "gpu_32" it runs on CPU but not on GPU. It's almost like the options are not getting passed to the opencl compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this same problem when running under 10.7.3, while a machine on 10.7.5 worked fine.  I noticed the `CVMCompiler` process was crashing after each invocation of my app.

Inspecting the stack trace, I noticed it was crashing when trying to parse the bitcode for compilation into native code.   Since the parsing of the bitcode failed failed, there was no resulting compiled program for `gclExecKernelAPPLE()` to execute, hence the error.

Try upgrading to 10.7.5, or indeed 10.8 and the problem should go away.  (I just tested this and it does indeed fix the problem.)

Comment: Perhaps you could test the code after upgrading and upvote the answer if it fixes the problem? Otherwise, let us know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Don't worry Gavinb I will do exactly that when time permits. For now I'm too busy to check if this solves my problem but will come back here as soon as I know anything more about it.

Comment: I'm having almost the same problem. The error I get is `-44`, and it does not work on CPU nor GPU. Your answer, gavinb is not helping me out (unfortunately). I'm on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) DP3, using XCode5-DP1.

Comment: @SergioMoura the error code -44 means `CL_INVALID_PROGRAM` (as per `cl.h`). It sounds like there's a compilation error in your kernel but you're still trying to execute it. Ensure you check the return codes in the compilation and link stages to see what the root cause is.